# RingtonePreference: Is it possible to change the dialog title?

Tags: android

By default, the title of the RingtonePreference dialog is "Ringtones".  I'd like to change it to something else, but I'm not seeing an obivous way to do that.

Setting the title in the xml does not work:

```
<RingtonePreference 
    android:key="@string/pref_key_notifications_sound"
    android:title="@string/prefs_notification_sound"
    android:ringtoneType="notification"
    android:showDefault="true"
    android:showSilent="true"
    android:persistent="true"
    />
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure it's possible. Besides, there is no guarantee the RingtonePreference is going to open the System's ringtone picker. The user might have another app installed that has an activity with the [android.intent.action.RINGTONE_PICKER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager.html#ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER) intent filter declared in the manifest and he might even have it as the default Ringtone picker.

You might implement a custom RingtonePreference and a custom RingtonePickerActivity and force your custom Ringtone picker to be open but you might irritate your users.

If I may ask, for what reason would you like to change it anyway?

Comment: I didn't realize that the system picker could be replaced.

Comment: I need to change it since we are developing a non-phone device.

Comment: What do you mean by a non-phone device? You mean a tablet?
In that case, you will need to implement your own RingtonePicker and probably your own RingtonePreference

Comment: Not a tablet... infotainment system.  I suspect you are correct and I'll need to write our own picker.